# Haskell: Not in scope: type constructor or class 'Board'

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to follow a tutorial in my Programming in Haskell book, but I get an error when I'm trying to run this directly copy pasted code from the book, can anyone see what's wrong?

```
error:
Not in scope: type constructor or class 'Board'
putBoard :: Board -> IO ()
```

```
putRow :: Int -> Int -> IO ()
putRow row num = do putStr (show row)
                    putStr ": "
                    putStrLn (concat (replicate num "* "))

putBoard :: Board -> IO ()
putBoard [a,b,c,d,e] = do putRow 1 a
                          putRow 2 b
                          putRow 3 c
                          putRow 4 d
                          putRow 5 e
```

Comment: `Board` should have been defined earlier in the book. Maybe a `type Board = [Int]`?

Comment: See: https://staff.emu.edu.tr/zekibayram/Documents/courses/CMPE462/Haskell%20code/nim.hs.txt for the full source code to the example.